Advice on piano composition
straight to the point
I'm better at composing for orchestra cause i could imagine melodies in my head that are not extremely complicated but complement each other.
It's easier to write imitation in orchestra composition or string
But when i'm trying to write a piano piece they turn out boring or not ( complex enough )
Maybe i'm not good at improvising and need a lot more practice on my piano skills
I usually sketch out the melodies in my head
And then arrange the form
Then i go and develop it along with the harmony i already had in mind
But it usually turns out like chopin nocturnes or mozart sonatas
Which is it that i need to work on
more ?
Edit: link of my latest works for strings and piano
https://files.fm/u/h6a9j6huus

You really need to provide example of what you think is your good orchestral stuff and boring piano stuff. Otherwise there is literally nothing to judge and no suggestions to make. I suspect your orchestral stuff may not necessarily be great melodic writing, but could be effective simply from orchestration effects.

I just included a link to 2 of my works with score, i have long way to go but i felt more satisfied with the piece for quartet

My first thought is that you need to listen to (and perhaps learn to play) a wider variety of music. When one gets stuck on Chopin Nocturnes and Mozart Sonatas, it can be because one hasn't sufficiently studied other composers and types of composition.
Try studying Bach, Scriabin, Bartók, and Philip Glass as a starting point for understanding widely varied ways to construct music that might help get you out of your rut.

This is going to be helpful . It has happend when i was playing a major composer's piece and an idea popped in my mind

I find this situation to be fairly common, whether we be proper composers or lyrical, melodic everyday songwriters.
We humans tend to fall into ruts, and end up, somehow, coming up with the same-sounding melodies, chords, and chord progression.
As a songwriter working primarily from the guitar player standpoint, I find myself crafting melodies and chord structures that are tired and/or unsatisfying.
One thing I have found for myself, and can recommend to you, is to craft or phrase a chord and a key that you aren't used to playing in, and then jump (with little to no forethought) into a different chord or key that would not be intuitively complimentary. And then repeat that sequence and transition.
Over and over again, until your find a tempo and a rhythm that makes it work in your head.
Within a minute or two, your brain will either say to you, "Wow. That's odd, but I kind of like it," or "No. That's just too weird and ugly".
If it's the former and not the latter, now you have a new platform for a new, interesting melody.
Then jump right into the deep end of the pool. Open your mind up to a melody and harmony that would compliment your new two chord beginning, and pretty soon you will be swimming in new and wondrous waters.
It works for me, every time.

Very great advice actually , but i'm currently trying to master the classical music and i really need to rely on some fundamentals and rules of harmony and ..

Understood. Good luck with it!
And Merry Christmas, by the way.
